# Intersection theory on M_{g,n}

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, intersection-theory, gromov-witten-theory

Is there a paper\book that lists the top intersections of Hodge classes and tautological classes on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ for small $g$ and $k$, e.g. $g=2,3$ and $k=0,1,2$ ?

Comment: I am aware of a Macaulay based program doing this but I am looking for some printed numbers.

Comment: Perhaps Chapter 2 of http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~freixas/Site/Recherche_files/SingARR_arxiv.pdf could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps these papers could be useful:

- C. Faber, "*Maple program for calculating intersection numbers on moduli spaces of curves*", (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/programs/index.html).
- S. Yang, "*Intersection numbers on $\overline{M}_{g,n}$*", (http://msp.org/jsag/2010/2-1/jsag-v2-n1-p01-s.pdf).

The algorithm of the second paper has been implemented in this MacAulay2 package: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.6.0.1-20131031-2/share/doc/Macaulay2/HodgeIntegrals/html/.

With this you can easily compute intersections of tautological classes on $\overline{M}_{g,n}$  for small values of $g,n$.